# Live stream video and capture input from the user and send it to Raspberry Pi Robot

Tags: browser, video-streaming, raspberry-pi, http-live-streaming, user-interaction

Need Help!

Let's assume I have a robot in a room with a camera on it. I need the video source to be available live on a website. I don't want any latency at all (assuming that I have a good internet connection). Also if a user presses any keys while on the website, the robot needs to detect it and do actions accordingly. Now, I can handle all the actions the robot needs to do once I get the keys. There's a raspberry pi on the robot.

What would be the easiest way where we could achieve a bi-directional communication (one direction being video and another being plain text) between a browser and my robot, keeping the communication as fast as possible.

*PS: I tried initiating a Google hangout and embedding the video, but there's a latency of atleast 1 minute.*

Comment: Can raspberry pi handle websockets? I've heard thats a pretty good way to communicate server/client. I haven't used them, but it might be something to look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple to do. get the camera for Raspberry Pi from here.

http://www.adafruit.com/products/1367

You could use Motion JPEG for transmitting the video. Follow the instructions below.

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/stream-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-to-web-browsers-even-on-ios-and-android

Once you the the IP of your video stream, you could display it in a website.

To send commands to rap pi, whats the complication ? If your Rasp. pi have an internet (it should be for the video stream), you could write a program to read commands from your browser.

Comment: I don't know but I am accepting your answer for your efforts. :) Thanks!